# ActiveAdmin Form: has_many :through as check boxes with additional data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

I am having a pretty basic `has_many :through`setup:

```
class Housing < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :facilities_housings
  has_many :facilities, through: :facilities_housings

  ...
end

class Facility < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :facilities_housings
  has_many :housings, through: :facilities_housings

  ...
end

class FacilitiesHousing < ApplicationRecord

 belongs_to :facility, inverse_of: :facilities_housings
 belongs_to :housing, inverse_of: :facilities_housings

 ...
end
```

I want to create a form which looks like like this:

[Form Mockup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VfA5M.png)

All Facilities should be listed and added/removed depending on the first checkbox.

I know this is pretty trivial to do with the `has_many`from helper included in activeadmin but the UX is not great for this use case.

Answer (score 0):

Is that a question?  [#4724](https://github.com/activeadmin/activeadmin/issues/4724) and [#4719](https://github.com/activeadmin/activeadmin/issues/4719) might apply.  If the basic functionality provided by ActiveAdmin is insufficient then you can override with your own partial and custom Javascript.